# Multiple Arrays in Multiple UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I know how to get a array in `UITableViewCell`:

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",array];
```

but how to put different arrays in multiple `UITableViewCell`

```
Like first cell: array.
```

`secondcell:array1`.

```
thirdcell: array2.
```

and also how to make mutiple lines in each cell,
which should look like:

```
A

B

C

D
```

inside a `UItableViewCell`

Comment: can you please put the reason after negative marking

Comment: those who down vote please ,please make sure that you cast your comment/reason for it before leaving, anonymous votes will help no one!

Comment: Is your requirement is like Quiz.. I mean Question and options ?

Comment: no! I just used ABCD's for better understanding

Comment: @pradeepj see the code which is simple flow with your requirement and if you want to add multiple line to cell and also some controlls in cell then its very easy, just add as a subview to cell and set frame which you want and after just set the height of the cell dude.. :)

Comment: make a custom cell.. It will solve all your issues..

Comment: @ParasJoshi i want many lines of subview, means different arrays in each cell one by one?

Comment: ok just wait i give one example dude see in my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Add value from different array in different cell like bellow..  Also i add controls in `UITableCell` for just an example which through you can add multiple controls in the cell with frame..

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {    
         static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"gridCell";

        UITableViewCell *yourCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

        if(yourCell == nil)        
        {
            yourCell =  [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }

        if(indexPath.row == 0)        
        {
          yourCell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",array];
          UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
          lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",array];
          lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
          [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 5, 200, 31)];    /// Set Frame which you want for every controls...
          // you can also add UITextView,etc..
          [yourCell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

         UILabel *lbl2= [[UILabel alloc]init];
          [lbl2 setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 31, 200, 31)];        
          lbl2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",array1];
          lbl2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

         lbl2.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

         [yourCell.contentView addSubview:lbl2];
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)        
        {
          yourCell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",array1];
          ///ADD also Controls here if you want to in this cell also...or every cell also then write and add subview outside from this if condition

        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 2)        
        {
          yourCell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",array2];
        }

        return yourCell;
    }
```

AND  if you want to Add multiple line in one cell then just add `UILable` or any other controls and set the frame and add as a subview of cell and also set height of the cell with bellow method...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    //height of table row
    return 80;///give the height to cell which you want here
}
```

Comment: thanks Paras u rocks!...what about multiple lines in same cell!?

Comment: @pradeepj just add the as a subview the controls to cell for example [Cell.contentView addSubview:yourLable]; and set frame which you want to your lable and just set the height of the raw with i defined method dude.. :)

Comment: multiple sub views? i want

Comment: @pradeepj now i add two subview for an example dude... which through you can understand how can you add another controls also so... give the value which you want  :)

Comment: someone give me the dawn-vote, can you explain why give me the dawn vote?? whats wrong??

Comment: This is non sense with negative mark without reason..stackoverflow should not consider this

Comment: yes dude you are right..